# How to use different Info.plist for debug and release: Build input file cannot be found: Info-Release.plist

Tags: xcode

Error:

```
Build input file cannot be found: '<path>/AppName/Info-Release.plist' (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

1. I have made a "dublicate" of the Info.plist
2. Named the two files, "Info-Release.info" and Info-Debug.plist"
3. Edited "Target/Build Settings/Info.plist File" to: AppName/Info-$(CONFIGURATION).plist
4. I can do cat AppName/Info-Release.plist
5. Tried both adding and removing the *.plist files from "Target/Build Phases/copy Bundle Resources.
6. Removed files from Derived Data folder.

Do you know whet to du?

Comment: I’m sorry, but this is going to sound silly, but is your error messages saying `…/AppName/Info-Release.plist` (the “project folder”) or `…/AppName/AppName/Info-Release.plist` (the “target folder”)? And are your plists in the project folder or the target folder?

Comment: It just say “AppName/Info-Release.plots”. But thank you for asking, I am away from my computer, but it makes me think if it has to du with groups. Do a group not match with file system?

Comment: To make it complicated, you can create a group that mirrors the file system (generally the result of "New Group") and you can create one that doesn't (e.g., "New Group without Folder", yielding an icon in Xcode that looks like a folder, but with a tiny tringle in the lower left corner). Personally, I try to avoid group w/ out folder, as it gets confusing having Xcode represent different structure than file system and/or my source control repos. And I do move these files into separate folder and change the plist build setting to explicitly reference that folder.

Comment: But, bottom line, the error message is telling you the full path of where it's looking for the file, and if you navigate to that folder in Finder or Terminal, I suspect you'll find it's not there, but accidentally in some other directory (in a group folder, in the project root folder, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, trouble is that the file is actually there... hmm

Comment: If you're 100% about the path (the folders/groups are a common source of confusion, something that I've done more than once), then it's likely something simple like spaces, capitalization, file permissions. But I've used the pattern you outlined in your question without incident. Perhaps try repeating this process in a new, blank, test project and confirm you can get it to work there, before proceeding. If you have a reproducible example of the problem (without any of your proprietary/confidential code), then you can upload that blank project and we can take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks Rob, for making me do it once more :-) I am sorry to say, but I can not even say what was different in the process. Thanks again, I will come back if it reoccur ;-)

Comment: Well, one different was - that I delete the project and copied the source code. And then did the same as described in the question - same process but different :-)